# Django models - before save/create

Tags: django, django-models

I have two Models:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name='products')    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The categories follow a tree like structure and I want to add products only to 'leaf categories'.
When I call `my_category.products.create(...)` or similar and `my_category.is_leaf_node() == False` then it should fail.
The same for `my_category.children.create(...)` if my_category has products already then it should fail.
Those checks go in the save method? in a custom manager? or some where else? I would the verification to be at model level.

Comment: You can do that checking in the form.is_valid() method, if you are handling it from a form, if not, you can check it in the save().

Comment: You may want to look at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/ where you can customize validation for specific fields specifically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: I'm not using forms, I'd like to have the check at model level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper location for model-level validation is in the `clean()` function.  You can raise a `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError` here to describe your error.  Have a look at [the documentation for clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Comment: when is the clean function executed?

Comment: clean is called by full_clean, which is called during ModelForm validation.  If you aren't using ModelForm in some way, it is generally considered good to call object.full_clean() in a try block, catching ValidationError, before saving the object.  We need to know how you are saving objects if not through a standard way such as a model form or create view

Comment: Right now I'm just unit testing but then I'll use my models in a REST api with django-rest-framework.  
Following your advice I'm calling full_clean() in the save() method, should I catch the exception there or in an upper level?

Comment: The layer that is calling save() should be responsible for calling full_clean() as well, catching the exception in that layer.  Not inside of save.  For example, this is how ModelForm works.